# How to set a loop forwarding using one NIC to TX packets and RX them itself in DPDK testpmd?

Tags: dpdk

I want to implement a scene like this:

1. A packet received in NIC's RXQ 0
2. NIC gets it and puts it in it's TXQ 0
3. By some way(NIC's effort?), the packet will be sent to the NIC's RXQ 0, and back to step 1.

I think the forward mode `tx_first` is what I need.

**NIC:**
PMD: MLX5
version: 5.0-1.0.0.0

**DPDK Version: 20.11.1**

**full command line**

```
./testpmd.sh 0 11-12 1 1 testpmd0 3b:00.0
```

```
#testpmd.sh
#if [ $# -ne 6 ]
#then
#       echo $0" <socket_id> <core_list> <core_num> <queue_num> <prefix>"
#       exit 255
#fi
        ./build/app/dpdk-testpmd -l $2 -n 4 \
        --socket-mem=2048,2048 \
        -a $6,txq_inline=200,txq_mpw
        --file-prefix=$5 \
        -- \
        -i \
        --mbcache=512 \
        --txonly-multi-flow \
        --rxd=2048 --txd=2048 \
        --rxq=$4 --txq=$4 \
        --nb-cores=$3 \
        --port-topology=loop \
        --numa --socket-num=$1 --port-numa-config=0,$1 --ring-numa-config=0,3,$1
```

But after I set command line arg `--port-topology=loop` and tried the `start tx_first`

The stream is:

```
testpmd> start tx_first
io packet forwarding - ports=1 - cores=1 - streams=1 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native
Logical Core 12 (socket 0) forwards packets on 1 streams:
  RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00
```

I got the stats:

```
testpmd> show fwd stats all

  ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
  RX-packets: 6              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 6
  TX-packets: 38             TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 38
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  +++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
  RX-packets: 6              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 6
  TX-packets: 38             TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 38
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

```
#32 same packets like this
restore info: - no tunnel info - no outer header - no miss group
  src=04:3F:72:CB:21:46 - dst=02:00:00:00:00:00 - type=0x0800 - length=64 - nb_segs=1 - sw ptype: L2_ETHER L3_IPV4 L4_UDP  - l2_len=14 - l3_len=20 - l4_len=8 - Send queue=0x0
  ol_flags: PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_IP_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_OUTER_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN

# discrete but same packets received
testpmd> port 0/queue 0: received 1 packets
restore info: - no tunnel info - no outer header - no miss group
  src=F4:74:88:8C:11:86 - dst=01:80:C2:00:00:00 - type=0x0069 - length=119 - nb_segs=1 - hw ptype: L2_ETHER  - sw ptype: L2_ETHER  - l2_len=14 - Receive queue=0x0
  ol_flags: PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_IP_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_OUTER_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN
port 0/queue 0: sent 1 packets
restore info: - no tunnel info - no outer header - no miss group
  src=F4:74:88:8C:11:86 - dst=01:80:C2:00:00:00 - type=0x0069 - length=119 - nb_segs=1 - hw ptype: L2_ETHER  - sw ptype: L2_ETHER  - l2_len=14 - Send queue=0x0
  ol_flags: PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_IP_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_OUTER_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN
port 0/queue 0: received 1 packets
restore info: - no tunnel info - no outer header - no miss group
  src=F4:74:88:8C:11:86 - dst=01:80:C2:00:00:00 - type=0x0069 - length=119 - nb_segs=1 - hw ptype: L2_ETHER  - sw ptype: L2_ETHER  - l2_len=14 - Receive queue=0x0
  ol_flags: PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_IP_CKSUM_UNKNOWN PKT_RX_OUTER_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN
```

The NIC didn't RX the Tx packets it sent, why?

Comment: can you please share your `1) cmd line, 2) nic used, 3) DPDK version` for a bit more clarity. When you put dpdk-testmpd 32 pkts will be sent out first. Since I see 6 packets RX and 38 pacekts as TX, I think the application is forwarding the packets properly. Please set verbose as `4` and check the logs.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have updated information you noticed. What makes me confused is that where is my first 32 packets? It seems that when the NIC got packets in RXQ , then it puts packets in it's TXQ, and the packets just, disappear?

Comment: TX stands for DPDK PMD stats representing packets triggered for DMA from Huigepage mbuf to MXL5 asic. so there are 38 packets done for the same. Since there is no information to which DPDK port is connected, it is hard to tell where the packet is sent. Based on the logs, Based on mac address `01:80:C2:00:00:00` this looks like spanning tree packet, which means your MXl5 is connected to switch.

Comment: I humbly request to get familiar with your setup and debug where the NIC is connected. I can set aside couple of minutes to help so via skype, hangout or zoom. But please be prepared to debug.

Comment: For some reason I can't use IMs today... But what confused me is , I just want to receive and sent packet at the same port, no cable is needed, right? The reason why it doesn't work is my wrong operation or some debug(setup or NIC connection)?

Comment: As your mentioned. mac address has it's meaning, what's `02:00:00:00:00:00` 's meaning?

Comment: once you are ready for chat/call for debugging please let me know. Please update your question with setup details `how it is connected too`

Comment: @VipinVarghese I'm available now, can we chat via hangout?  xzp9917@gmail.com this is my email.

Comment: shared invite waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set DPDK application `dpdk-tespmd` in loopback mode it requires `2 DPDK ports` and `--port-topology=loop`.

But if there is only 1 Physical NIC port there are a couple of options to set the DPDK interface in loopback mode

1. Physical transreciever where TX and RX and cross-connected
2. NIC with embedded switch configured in `fabric loopback mode`
3. if connected to external switch enabling `MAC|PHY loopback` on switch.

Once configured in any of the above 3 modes, run the following commands

1. set eth-peer 0 [desired DST MAC address]
2. set fwd macswp
3. start tx_first

to validate the same without physical NIC start testpmd as `./build/app/testpmd -l 2-3 --vdev=net_tap0,iface=testDpdk0 -- -i --rxq=1 --txq=1`. Setting verbosity for RX packet `set verbose 2`

Comment: @Alexcured if the information and live debug has helped please accept|upvote to close this.